# Will a soldering tip from a WEP-70 fit an old WECP-20?

Tags: soldering

I recently found my old soldering station from 20+ years ago - a WECP-20

But the soldering tip need replacing and one alternative, that looks the same, is the one fitting a WEP-70.

Will the WEP-70 tip fit the WECP-20 station?

Comment: Measure the old one and then check the details of the new one...

Comment: Very good idea, but I have to order it online and there is no specifications or measurements listed. Of course I could try to Google it.

Comment: a quick google search makes some details of dimensions available : https://www.weidinger.eu/en/shop/soldering_equipment/weller/weller_soldering_and_desoldering_tips/weller_soldering_tips_et-series/wl43732

Comment: weidinger.eu does have a ["Contact & service" form](https://www.weidinger.eu/en/contact_and_service).